# cu3er background issue

Tags: html, css, flash

I'm using a set of PNGs to run my cu3er slides. They keep the transparency, until the transition and then they're boxed with a white background. Is there a way to either keep it transparent or set the background color? http://205.186.139.193/ is the test site

Javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var flashvars = {};
  flashvars.xml = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/slider/cu3er.php";
  flashvars.font = "font.swf";
  var attributes = {};
  attributes.wmode = "transparent";
  attributes.id = "slider";
  swfobject.embedSWF("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/slider/cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "963", "283", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
  #cu3er-container{ background: #000; }
  #header_cu3er { background: #000; }
```

cu3er Settings:

```
    <cu3er>
 <settings>

   <auto_play >
          <defaults symbol="circular" />
          <tweenIn tint="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.65"  />
          <tweenOut tint="0xffffff" alpha="0" />
          <tweenOver alpha="0" />
      </auto_play>

   <prev_button>
   <defaults round_corners="5,5,5,5"/>
   <tweenOver tint="0xFFFFFF" scaleX="1.1" scaleY="1.1"/>
   <tweenOut tint="0x000000" />
  </prev_button>

     <prev_symbol>
   <tweenOver tint="0x000000" />   
  </prev_symbol>

     <next_button>
   <defaults round_corners="5,5,5,5"/>   
   <tweenOver tint="0xFFFFFF"  scaleX="1.1" scaleY="1.1"/>
   <tweenOut tint="0x000000" />
  </next_button>

     <next_symbol>
   <tweenOver tint="0x000000" />
  </next_symbol> 
 </settings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hows about changing my javascript to add attributes.bgcolor and removing wmode?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.xml = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/slider/cu3er.php";
    flashvars.font = "font.swf";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.bgcolor = "d2d2d2";
    attributes.id = "slider";
    swfobject.embedSWF("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/slider/cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "980", "500", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
    </script>
```

Yep, that fixes it!